# Rails clock display

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, setinterval, clock

I have an application that needs to display a clock on the index page.
So I have a static controller like this:

controllers/static_controller.rb:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S ")
  end

  def get_time
    @time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S ")
    render partial: "date"
  end

end
```

and I have this on views/static/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="time-container">
   <%= render partial: "date" %>
</div>
```

and this partial views/static/_date.html.erb that contains just the var:

```
  <%=@time%>
```

I used this JS function to try to update time on assets/javascripts/static.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.time-container').load('/static/get_time');

    }, 1000);
});
```

My routes.rb are this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "static#index"
  resources :static

end
```

This way, the clock shows up when the page loads, but it stays always the same and does not update. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do your javascript console on the browser show any error?

Comment: Yes: GET http://localhost:3000/static/get_time 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Am I missing a route config?

Comment: yeap.. post your routes file to see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes don't match with the flow you built.

You just were lucky that static/index worked because its included within the resources statement.

Take out the:

```
resources :static
```

And replace with

```
get 'static/index'
get 'static/get_time'
```